# Orthodoxy: Does baptism grant dispensations from vows previously made as a protestant?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, baptism

The title is pretty self explanatory. I have made some vows during psychotic episodes from when I was an emotionally charged and immature protestant many years ago. I was recently just now received into the Holy Russian Orthodox Church. Does virtue of baptism grant me dispensation from my previous vows? (Note: Never married/divorced.)

Comment: I can speak specifically to Russian Orthodox, but if you made a vow during a psychotic episode, most Christians would not hold you to account for that.

Comment: The Gospel provides forgiveness from all sins, including the sin of breaking a vow. Any reason why you wouldn't just confess your sins like normal?

Comment: The situation with vows made during a period of mental illness is specific enough that you should get personal spiritual advice, which this site cannot and will not provide. Talk to a leader or counsellor in your church.

Comment: Jesus told us not to make vows. Insofar as there may be sin pertaining to them, it's most likely that the problem was the making of the vow, not a later breaking of something sinful or impractical. But talk to your priest or adviser re: the details, as they matter.

Comment: What sort of vows?

Comment: Have you talked to your priest/spiritual father about this?